# PHP Storm: how to remove project without deleting files

Tags: phpstorm

I accidentally made the entire PHPstormProjects folder, which contains all of my projects, and turned it into a project. When I realized my mistake, I deleted all the files which I had uploaded into the project, but it still lists it as a PHPStorm Project.

I don't want to simply delete the project, as it contains all of my other projects. Is there any way to 'unset' a PHP project?

Comment: Maybe remove the **.idea** folder from PHPstormProjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On "Welcome" screen (when all projects are closed) just select unwanted project and press <kbd>Del</kbd> key.

To make sure that IDE will not treat this folder as a Project -- just delete project settings (`.idea` subfolder) when that project is closed.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I just removed the .idea folder and its back to normal

Comment: Can you point to a documentation page confirming that deleting the .idea folder is indeed the official and right way to "uncreate a project from existing sources"?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski `.idea` subfolder is where this project settings are stored (unless you did some manipulation so such folder can be located elsewhere). You can move whole folder onto another computer and when you choose "Open folder" in PhpStorm, once it will see that folder it will show special "project here" icon. No ideas what you mean by your *"the official and right way"*. What problem do you have that you need such "assurance"? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/project-and-ide-settings.html#d428084e59